# print data right aligned in column in python

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have a script which has a column field as:

```
States = ['Massachusetts', 'Pennsylvania','Utah','Ohio','California']
```

I  do a couple of file and data processing and print the field as:

```
print '-'*200
print 'Name\tPopulation\tAverage Income\Crime Rate'
print '-'*200
for s in States:
    print '%s\t%s/%s\t%s\t%s' % (s, p_f, p_m, av, cr)
```

The output looks like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name    Population    Avergae Income    Crime Rate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Massachusetts    100000/100000    5000 50
Pennsylvania     100000/100000    5000 50
Utah 100000/100000    5000 50
Ohio 100000/100000    5000 50
California 100000/100000    5000 50
```

However, I would like data to be aligned right side

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
         Name       Population    Avergae Income    Crime Rate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Massachusetts    100000/100000              5000            50
 Pennsylvania    100000/100000              5000            50
         Utah    100000/100000              5000            50
         Ohio    100000/100000              5000            50
   California    100000/100000              5000            50
```

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data) because all I have done is modified Sven Marnach's code slightly.

```
states = ['Massachusetts', 'Pennsylvania','Utah','Ohio','California']
columns = ['Name', 'Population', 'Average Income', 'Crime Rate']

row_format = '{:>17}' * (len(columns))
print '-'*200
print row_format.format(*columns)
print '-'*200

for state in states:
    state_data = [p_f + '/' + p_m, av, cr]
    print row_format.format(state, *state_data)
```

The `row_format` is used to set up the column width and spacing. Change the value of the `17` to use a different number of characters. The `format(...)` is used to insert your values with the correct spacing.